# Game Center causing app crash

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, crash

My app is crashing when Game Center is logged in, all is fine through the simulator and in sandbox mode on all devices. I have had some negative feedback regarding the crashes so have started to look through it. I thought it was solved so got the update out, but I was wrong.

I have this crash report from my phone but am some what baffled.

```
Version:             1.4 (1.4)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-02-22 09:18:36.959 +0000
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.4 (11B554a)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x311eff46 __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b57f6aa objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x311f38e2 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 198
3   CoreFoundation                  0x311f21c6 ___forwarding___ + 702
4   CoreFoundation                  0x311414d4 __forwarding_prep_0___ + 20
5   CommanderCool                   0x000a13a2 0x67000 + 238498
6   CommanderCool                   0x00098a30 0x67000 + 203312
7   CommanderCool                   0x00098688 0x67000 + 202376
8   CommanderCool                   0x000886a6 0x67000 + 136870
9   CommanderCool                   0x0008a21a 0x67000 + 143898
10  CommanderCool                   0x0009f50a 0x67000 + 230666
11  CommanderCool                   0x00082316 0x67000 + 111382
12  CommanderCool                   0x0007fa6e 0x67000 + 100974
13  CommanderCool                   0x0008198c 0x67000 + 108940
14  CommanderCool                   0x00087160 0x67000 + 131424
15  CommanderCool                   0x000ce93e 0x67000 + 424254
16  CommanderCool                   0x000e000a 0x67000 + 495626
17  QuartzCore                      0x336399ca CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 94
18  QuartzCore                      0x33639774 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 340
19  IOMobileFramebuffer             0x3621e768 IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 100
20  IOKit                           0x31ed1a70 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 244
21  CoreFoundation                  0x311afe1c __CFMachPortPerform + 132
22  CoreFoundation                  0x311ba9da __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 30
23  CoreFoundation                  0x311ba976 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 342
24  CoreFoundation                  0x311b914a __CFRunLoopRun + 1394
25  CoreFoundation                  0x31123c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
26  CoreFoundation                  0x31123a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
27  GraphicsServices                0x35e0227e GSEventRunModal + 134
28  UIKit                           0x339c7044 UIApplicationMain + 1132
29  CommanderCool                   0x0009d31e 0x67000 + 221982
30  CommanderCool                   0x0006ef24 0x67000 + 32548


Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bb3e1fc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3bba7a2e pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3baeeff8 abort + 72
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3ae1dcd2 abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3ae366e0 default_terminate_handler() + 248
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b57f91e _objc_terminate() + 190
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3ae341c4 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3ae33d28 __cxa_rethrow + 96
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b57f7f2 objc_exception_rethrow + 38
9   CoreFoundation                  0x31123c98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 636
10  CoreFoundation                  0x31123a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
11  GraphicsServices                0x35e0227e GSEventRunModal + 134
12  UIKit                           0x339c7044 UIApplicationMain + 1132
13  CommanderCool                   0x0009d31e 0x67000 + 221982
14  CommanderCool                   0x0006ef24 0x67000 + 32548

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bb2b83c kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3ba76e08 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3ba6639e _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$up + 34

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bb3ec7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3bba4dc6 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3bba4c80 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bb3ec7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3bba4dc6 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3bba4c80 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bb2ba8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bb2b888 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x311ba7be __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x311b8ee4 __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x31123c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x31123a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x301a6584 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 124
7   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x3019a99c CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 176
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3bba6c1a _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3bba6b8a _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3bba4c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bb2ba8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bb2b888 mach_msg + 44
2   AudioToolbox                    0x30ba5116 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Run() + 102
3   AudioToolbox                    0x30ba8348 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Entry(void*) + 4
4   AudioToolbox                    0x30ae5ba8 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 208
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3bba6c1a _pthread_body + 138
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3bba6b8a _pthread_start + 98
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3bba4c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bb2ba8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bb2b888 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x311ba7be __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x311b8ee4 __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x31123c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x31123a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   AudioToolbox                    0x30aff754 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 124
7   AudioToolbox                    0x30ae5ba8 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 208
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3bba6c1a _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3bba6b8a _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3bba4c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bb2ba8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bb2b888 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x311ba7be __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x311b8ee4 __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x31123c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x31123a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   Foundation                      0x31b5e2f2 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 314
7   Foundation                      0x31bd3c82 __NSThread__main__ + 1058
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3bba6c1a _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3bba6b8a _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3bba4c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bb3e440 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x311be680 __CFSocketManager + 480
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3bba6c1a _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3bba6b8a _pthread_start + 98
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3bba4c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00002060
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3d77b18c      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x27d9c594
    r8: 0x1550f940    r9: 0x00000001     r10: 0x0022fc14     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x27d9c588      lr: 0x3bba7a33      pc: 0x3bb3e1fc
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
```

Left out images as file was too big.

I'm using DDGameKitHelper and GKAchievementNotification to handle the game center notifications.

Comment: You need to symbolicate this crash log, so you can see what code was called. Importing this into Xcode should do it automatically, assuming you do it on the machine that made the build that crashed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. When I press re-symbolicate nothing happens. Just looking into how it should work

Comment: I couldnt symbolicate the log. I cannot replicate the crash in distribution build either as the issue is clearly when Game Center i running fully and not in sandbox. I have no clue where to start

Comment: If you can't symbolicate, and can't reproduce, you're pretty much out of luck.